# LaTeX code for "white square brackets" 〚 and 〛

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How does one make the symbol for a blackboard bold kind square brackets ,something like [[.The symbol being talked about is used for containing formulas whose truth values are being talked about in propositional logic.
Thanks and regards
An image of the symbol: [image]

Comment: the symbol i am talking about is something like [[ squeezed together to form one symbol used in propositional logic. e.g \tau [[phi]]=1

Comment: Finding an image on Google Images might help users determine the exact symbol you're referring to.

Comment: i have edited the question and added an image of the symbol.

Comment: If you use `unicode-math`, you can just use the Unicode characters ⟦ (U+27E6) and ⟧ (U+27E7). They work nicely with `\big` and `\left`/`\right` and the like. (Sadly I cannot post this as an answer.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are looking for

- `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` from the `stmaryrd` package
- `\textlbrackdbl` and `\textrbrackdbl` from the `textcomp` package

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is an online tool that can help you find latex symbols by drawing them.

[image: detexify-example]

Comment: If I could've upvoted more than once, I would've.

Comment: Detexify is great. It worked fine even with my limited drawing skills.