# A square bracket '[' with a double vertical line

Tags: symbols

Perhaps, that's a very easy question - I wonder what's the code of the symbol that looks like the square bracket `[` but whose vertical line is double, like in `||` represented by `$\|$`.

Comment: Have a look at these answers http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet

Comment: Questions like this tend to be closed as a duplicate of the question that Ludovic linked to above.  In this specific case, you might find the answer faster by looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/81785/86 (which was itself closed as a duplicate of the above question).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: thanks, I've spent a couple of minutes trying to draw this symbol in detexify, but I was not successful